# Anonymous Apex - Create/Insert new profile to scratch org

Tags: apex, scratch-org, execute-anonymous

Is it possible to create/insert Standard User Profile in Scratch Org using Anonymous Apex or Apex Class? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The Standard User Profile comes standard with Salesforce. You can't create a standard profile. If you want to *update* the existing profile, include the metadata for the profile in your package, and then deploy it with force:source:push or force:source:deploy.

Comment: Thank you for you answer... interasting but I don't have Standard User profile on me scratch org. Do i need some additional settings on me DevHub?

Comment: @SFguru The Standard User profile will depend on the settings in your Scratch Org Configuration File. Your Dev Hub has nothing to do with the type of org you'll create, unless you're on the Org Shape pilot.

Comment: Maybe you have some example? Thank you in advance! I didnt find it here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Comment: @SFguru I don't know of any setting that could do this. That's why I asked to look at your config file.

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the configuration file you have for your scratch org creation.